# How can I create facebook style vertical border line (layout)? :)

Tags: css

How can I create vertical border line on both (left, right) side like facebook using CSS??

I've read several posts on Stackoverflow, but I could not find exactly what I wanted...Anybody know how to make vertical lines(layout)?
Thank you :)

### facebook

```
 | contents |
 |          |
 |          | <-these two vertical lines on facebook
 |          |
 |          |
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just apply borders and shadow to these borders (you can change the box-shadow value to fit your needs). Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x2aJ3/3/)

```
.middle {
    width:400px;
    height:800px;
    border-left:1px solid #eeeeee;
    border-right:1px solid #eeeeee;
    margin:0 auto;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #888888;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two options:

1. use css borders and play with box-shadow too
2. use image lines there

both work fine. I would choose the css solution but there are others who create an image background and place it behind the main content area and then center all content on top of it.

Answer (score 0):

Specify your content width first. then use 
    margin : 0 auto;
it will keep your content in the middle of the page with both side equal space blank. then put dashed border on the content. try it. give your feedback.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `border-right` and `border-left` here is an example below

```
#middle-region{
width: 900px;
min-height: 600px;
border-right: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
border-left: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
margin: auto;
}
```